# Adding georeferencing data into tiff image

Tags: qgis, gdal, php, geotiff-tiff

I want to create a georeferenced `.tiff` file from a `.png` file. So I convert the .png into a normal `.tiff` file using the following command line :

```
convert image.png image.tiff
```

Here, all works fine, I have a valid `.tiff` file, which displays fine. Then, I want to add some georeferencing data in it. To do so, I found a tool called [`tiff2geotiff`](http://www.vapor.ucar.edu/page/tiff2geotiff), I'm using it like this :

```
tiff2geotiff -4 "+proj=latlong +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -c none -n "-122.5575664 38.5818201 -122.5449425 38.5896175" notgeoreferenced.tiff georeferenced.tiff
```

This gives me a **black image** which, imported in QGis, displays fine in the good place, except that it's black everywhere (proof that the *georeferenced data have been well added*).

Therefore, when I do :

```
gdalinfo georeferenced.tiff
```

I obtain :

```
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Bogus "StripByteCounts" field, ignoring and calculating from imagelength
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: araujo_tmp.tiff
Size is 1585, 979
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-122.557563781738281,38.589618682861328)
Pixel Size = (0.000007966552118,-0.000007972639275)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=georeferenced.tiff
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-122.5575638,  38.5896187) (122d33'27.23"W, 38d35'22.63"N)
Lower Left  (-122.5575638,  38.5818135) (122d33'27.23"W, 38d34'54.53"N)
Upper Right (-122.5449368,  38.5896187) (122d32'41.77"W, 38d35'22.63"N)
Lower Right (-122.5449368,  38.5818135) (122d32'41.77"W, 38d34'54.53"N)
Center      (-122.5512503,  38.5857161) (122d33' 4.50"W, 38d35' 8.58"N)
Band 1 Block=1585x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=1585x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=1585x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

**I think the first warning may be the problem...**

Is there someone who knows why or another way to do this ? I'm looking for solutions in command line or in `PHP`.

---

## Solution

**I found out `gdal_translate` can add georeferencing data into `.tiff` images**, so here is the command line which convert from png and add georeferencing data (you have to replace the extents (`llx ury urx lly`), of course):

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr llx ury urx lly pngfile.png tifffile.tiff
```

Comment: about your question if there are gdal php bindings, **PHP is not currently properly supported by GDAL/OGR.**    http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPhp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using `convert`, could you try to use `gdal_translate` to convert the png to tiff and then georeference it using gdal_warp (assuming you've created a tfw file for the tiff)?

Comment: Here is the command line I use now : `gdal_translate -scale pngfile.png tifffile.tiff`

Answer (score 5):

Do you know the extents of the image?  If you know the bounding coordinates of the image you can us gdal_translate with the -a_srs (this assigns the projection) and -a_ullr (this is the bounding coordinates).  I have used this to convert .jpg of sonar images from a low cost fishing sonar unit to geotiffs.

Comment: So you're saying that I don't need to use tiff2geotiff to add the extents of the image (yes I have them) ? :)
Cool ! Yes I see that in the documentation, I will use it instead of tiff2geotiff, thank you !

Comment: No problem, I am glad this will help